# Save and load a route into a windows phone bing map

Tags: c#, windows-phone, bing-maps

I was searching some examples and articles related to saving and loading a route into a bing map but i couldn't find anything, so currently i am asking if this is possible.

Please let me know if this is supported by the bing maps for windows phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use bing map api on my web
I`m not sure if it will work well
initialize the map using the following code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var map = null;

         function GetMap()
         {
            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),{credentials:"Your Bing Maps Key", mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road }); 

         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>`
```

add code to make the route request when the button is clicked, and add code to the RouteCallback function to set the map view and draw the route.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var map = null;

         function GetMap()
         {
            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),{credentials:"Your Bing Maps Key", mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road }); 


         }

         function ClickRoute(credentials)
         {

            map.getCredentials(MakeRouteRequest);
         }


         function MakeRouteRequest(credentials)
         {
            var routeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wp.0=" + document.getElementById('txtStart').value + "&wp.1=" + document.getElementById('txtEnd').value + "&routePathOutput=Points&output=json&jsonp=RouteCallback&key=" + credentials;

            CallRestService(routeRequest);

         }


          function RouteCallback(result) {


             if (result &&
                   result.resourceSets &&
                   result.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
                   result.resourceSets[0].resources &&
                   result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {

                     // Set the map view
                     var bbox = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].bbox;
                     var viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[0], bbox[1]), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[2], bbox[3]));
                     map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries});


                     // Draw the route
                     var routeline = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routePath.line;
                     var routepoints = new Array();

                     for (var i = 0; i < routeline.coordinates.length; i++) {

                         routepoints[i]=new Microsoft.Maps.Location(routeline.coordinates[i][0], routeline.coordinates[i][1]);
                     }


                     // Draw the route on the map
                     var routeshape = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(routepoints, {strokeColor:new Microsoft.Maps.Color(200,0,0,200)});
                     map.entities.push(routeshape);

                 }
         }


         function CallRestService(request) 
         {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("src", request);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
      <input id="txtStart" type="text" value="Seattle"/>
      <input id="txtEnd" type="text" value="Portland"/>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate Route" onclick="ClickRoute()"/>
   </body>
</html>
```